# How to search over whole cities in combobox

Tags: c#, combobox

I inserted about 18 cities in government field and I can search over each city I want by ID, but now I want to search over all of the cities by ID when I do not select any thing in combobox.

```
string c = "%";
c = comboBox1.Text;
int a;
a = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
a = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Person where ( PER_ID = '" + a + "' and  GOV_NAME_AR = '" + c + "') ", con);
cmd.CommandTimeout = 600;
con.Open();
SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if (rdr.HasRows)
{
    //  MessageBox.Show("Successfully found Data");
    //    SqlDataReader DR = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    BindingSource source = new BindingSource();
    dataGridView1.DataSource = source;
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("data not found");
}
con.Close();
```

Comment: what is a govt. field?

Comment: its a column name in my sql data base that include whole cities

Comment: @fubo do you understand the question?

Comment: no dear what do you mean

Comment: @babanjamal could you add more details, expected input /output? what is the current situation and what is the error / invalid result you get?

Comment: dear I do not have any error but when I select no thing in combobox I want the search to be in whole of the cities not specific city just

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change the statement in case of "nothing selected"

```
if (ComboBox.Text == string.Empty)
{   
    cmd.CommandText = "select * from Person where ( PER_ID = '" + a + "')";
}
```

Remarks:

- use variable names like `string sCity = "%";` instead of  `string c = "%";`
- use parameters for your sql statements `where ( PER_ID = @Person)` and `cmd.Parameters.Add("@Person", SqlDbType.Int32).Value = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);`

Comment: I will try it now

Comment: sorry Bro can I ask another question if you have a time @fubo

Answer (score 0):

If I get you correctly, you don't want where clause on GOV_NAME_AR when combobox1 is not selected.

```
if( ComboBox.SelectedItem == null ) {
   cmd.CommandText = "select * from Person where ( PER_ID = '" + a + "')";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do a check on the ComboBox.SelectedText like this:

```
if (comboBox1.SelectedText=="")
{
//SQL statement should not restrict on the c value
}
else
{
//Use your regular SQL query here.
}
```

Comment: I like the answer below better.